# Spark dataframe: row-to-row comparison

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here what I want to do is for each id sort the data based on the date. In this sorted data start from the second row and compare each row with the row just above it and tell in which column a change was made. Store this information in a new column.

The comparison needs to happen only if the id is same else the result is empty cell.

What i tried:
1) partition data based on id.
2) call MapPartition.
3) inside mappartition convert partition to list and sort by id and date
4) create a sliding windoe on this sorted list and compare the 0th and 1st row in each window. create a case class object with the result string.

As the first row of every partition won't be compared against anything add a case class object for this row with empty resutl_string.

```
val df_after_comparison=df_from_source.repartition(df_from_source("id")).mapPartitions(partition =>{
    if(partition != null ) {
      val iter=partition.toList.sortBy(Row => (Row.getAs[String]("id"), Row1.getAs[String]("date")))
      if (iter.length == 1) {
        iter.map(x => new newdata(x.getAs[String]("id"), x.getAs[String]("attribute1"),x.getAs[String]("date"), x.getAs[String]("attribute2"), "")).toList.iterator
      }
      else {
        val par = iter.sliding(2, 1).toList.map(x => {
          var result_string = ""
          if (x(0).getAs[String]("id") != x(1).getAs[String]("id")) {
               new newdata(x(1).getAs[String]("id"), x(1).getAs[String]("attribute1"), x(1).getAs[String]("date"), x(1).getAs[String]("attribute2"), "")
          }
          else {
            if (x(0).getAs[String]("attribute1") != x(1).getAs[String]("attribute1")) {
                result_string = result_string + " attribute1 "
            }
            if (x(0).getAs[String]("date") != x(1).getAs[String]("date")) {
                result_string = result_string + " date "
            }
            if (x(0).getAs[String]("attribute2") != x(1).getAs[String]("attribute2")) {
                result_string = result_string + " attribute2 "
            }
                new newdata(x(1).getAs[String]("id"), x(1).getAs[String]("attribute1"), x(1).getAs[String]("panel_date1"), x(1).getAs[String]("attribute2"), result_string)
            }
        }
        )
            (new newdata(iter.head.getAs[String]("id"), iter.head.getAs[String]("attribute1"), iter.head.getAs[String]("panel_date1"), iter.head.getAs[String]("attribute2"), "") +: par).iterator
        }
    }
    else{
        Iterator.empty
    }
```

})

This works fine in local mode but fails on the cluster. Any help is welcome.
sample expected output:
+-----------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+

|               id|attribute1|               date|     attribute2|       result_string|

+-----------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+

|10000010000000001|         1|2016-01-01 00:00:00|         ITEM_3|                        | //first row for this id so no comparison

|10000010000000001|         3|2016-01-02 00:00:00|         ITEM_4| attribute1  date...| //change in 3 columns

|10000010000000001|         3|2016-02-24 00:00:00|         ITEM_5|    date  attribute2|

|10000010000000001|         3|2016-02-31 00:00:00|         ITEM_6|    date  attribute2|

|10000010000000001|         3|2016-03-02 00:00:00|         ITEM_7|    date  attribute2|

|10000010000000001|         3|2016-03-03 00:00:00|         ITEM_8|    date  attribute2|

|10000010000000001|         3|2016-03-08 00:00:00|         ITEM_9|    date  attribute2|

|10000010000000001|         3|2016-03-18 00:00:00|        ITEM_10|    date  attribute2|

|10000010000000004|         1|2016-04-03 00:00:00|ITEM_1         |                    |//new id so result_string is empty

|10000010000000006|         1|2016-01-01 00:00:00|ITEM_2         |                    |

|10000010000000006|         2|2016-04-05 00:00:00|ITEM_1         | attribute1  date...|

|10000010000000030|         2|2016-04-04 00:00:00|ITEM_1         |                    |

+-----------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+

Comment: you have to know you will lose change if you compare data between different partitions.

Comment: here I am using mapPartition for that, it will perform the comparion for rows in one partition only and not compare rows from different partitions.